# How do I configure nginx to show location specific error messages?

Tags: nginx, custom-error-pages

Suppose I have two sets of actions on my base_url:

- base_url/action_a
- base_url/everything_else

When my any action raises a 500, I want to show a custom 500.html but for a 500 raised by action_a I want to bypass the custom 500.html but let the action's response suffice.

How can I configure `action_a` to not use the error_page directive in the nginx configuration?

Currently, I can serve my custom 500.html generically via

```
error_page 501 502 503 504 505 /50X.html;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location /base_url/action_a {
    error_page 501 502 503 504 505 /some_page.html;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/error_page
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html